# Share .mp3 file located in /res/raw/ to WhatsApp

Tags: android, audio, mp3, share, whatsapp

I am writing a ringtone app in Android (API 29) and I want to share the sounds, stored in MP3 format in the `/res/raw/` folder, via WhatsApp. I am using this code:

```
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.yeah);
    share.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    share.setType("audio/mp3");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share"));
```

But every time I select a chat to send the audio file, I get a WhatsApp error telling me the file could not be shared. I've seen other apps do what I want **WITHOUT** requesting permissions to write to the external storage. Any clues how this has been done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve the problem by mixing CommonsWare answer, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709210/creating-a-file-object-from-a-resource) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516126/fileprovider-illegalargumentexception-failed-to-find-configured-root). Thanks to all in advance!

**Step by step solution:**

*First, let's start with some XML.*

1. Configure `AndroidManifest.xml` and add the following lines inside the `<application>` section. I put them in between my `</activity>` and `</application>` closing tags, but please take this placement as my personal choice: it might not work for you depending on your manifest layout.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<provider
   android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
   android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
   android:exported="false"
   android:grantUriPermissions="true">
   <meta-data
      android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
      android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

As I am using API 29, I'm [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) libraries. In case you want to use it too consider running the AndroidX migration wizard by clicking `Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX...` in Android Studio at your own risk.

2. Now create a file in `/res/xml` with the name `file_paths.xml` and fill it as follows:

**file_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <cache-path name="my_sounds" path="/"/>
</paths>
```

Note the `my_sounds` name is arbitrary. The `/` in the `path` field is where in the cache path your file will be stored. I just let it like that for the sake of ease. Should you not want to use a cache path, [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider?hl=en#SpecifyFiles) is the complete list of available tags you can use.

*Now we will head back to Java and start coding the method that will handle the sharing. First of all we need to copy the file in our resource folder to a `File` object. This `File`, however, needs to be pointing to a path created by the File Provider we configured in the XML part. Let's divide the tasks:*

1. Create an `InputStream` with your file's data and fill a `File` with it with an auxiliary procedure.

**public void handleMediaSend(int position)**

```
File sound;
try {
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(sounds.get(position).getSound()); // equivalent to R.raw.yoursound
    sound = File.createTempFile("sound", ".mp3");
    copyFile(inputStream, new FileOutputStream(sound));
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Can't create temp file", e);
}
```

**Auxiliary procedure:**

```
private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
```

Now your resource has been successfully transferred to a cached directory (use the debugger to see which one) inside your Internal Storage.

4. Get an `Uri` and share the `File`.

```
final String AUTHORITY = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider";
Uri uri = getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), AUTHORITY, sound);
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("audio/mp3"); // or whatever.
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share"));
```

Putting it all together we will end up with this method:

**Full method**

```
public void handleMediaSend(int position) { // Depends on your implementation.
    File sound;
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(sounds.get(position).getSound()); // equivalent to R.raw.yoursound
        sound = File.createTempFile("sound", ".mp3");
        copyFile(inputStream, new FileOutputStream(sound));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can't create temp file", e);
    }

    final String AUTHORITY = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider";
    Uri uri = getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), AUTHORITY, sound);
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("audio/mp3"); // or whatever.
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> But every time I select a chat to send the audio file, I get a WhatsApp error telling me the file could not be shared

Few apps support the obscure `android.resource` scheme very well. Also, [`EXTRA_STREAM` is documented to take a `content` `Uri`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Intent#extra_stream), not an `android.resource` `Uri`.

> Any clues how this has been done?

Make a copy of the raw resource to a file on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), such as in `getCacheDir()`. You can use the `Resources` object you get from calling `getResources()` a `Context` to get access to the raw resource (using `openRawResource()`). Then, [configure `FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider?hl=en) to serve from there, and use `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` to get a `Uri` to use with `ACTION_SEND`. Be sure to add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` on the `Intent`.

[This sample Java app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/v1.0/PdfProvider) (and [its Kotlin equivalent](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/v1.0/PdfProvider)) demonstrate the basic technique. In my case, I am storing a PDF as an asset instead of your storing an MP3 as a raw resource, so that part will require some minor adjustments.

Alternatively, you can write your own `ContentProvider` from scratch to serve your raw resource, then use a `Uri` supported by that provider in your `Intent`.